# Is it true that $X\iff Y$ is equivalent to $[X\land Y]\lor [\neg X \land \neg Y]$?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Is it true that $X\iff Y$ is equivalent to $[X\land Y]\lor [\neg X \land \neg Y]$?

I don't see anything wrong with the statement. Could someone confirm?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed wrong, but that might be because you made a typo: the second "$\vee$" should be a "$\wedge$". Currently, the right statetment means "Either $X$ and $Y$ are both true, or one of $X$ or $Y$ is false," which is simply a tautology. What it should say is "Either $X$ and $Y$ are both true, or $X$ and $Y$ are both false."

Note that "$X$ and $Y$ are both false" is **not** the same as $\neg(X\wedge Y)$.

---

EDIT: Now the statement is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$(X\land Y)\lor (\neg X\lor\neg Y)$$ is the same as, by a standanrd rule "negation of conjunction"
$$(X\land Y)\lor \neg (  X\land  Y),$$ and the latter is always true.

However, the assertion $ X\Leftrightarrow Y$ can be false, therefore the desired equivalence does not hold.